# Improve the quality of android camera frame with openCV

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, javacv

I'm using openCV for Android.
I have got an app that can recognise a logo with the camera frame. The recognition is not as good as i expected and i think it's because my frames quality are bad.

My activity implements `CvCameraViewListener2` and got a preview of the frame :

```
<org.opencv.android.NativeCameraView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tutorial1_activity_native_surface_view"
    opencv:show_fps="true"
    opencv:camera_id="any" />
```

I capture frames with this method :

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) { // for every frame
    compteurFPS++;
    if(compteurFPS%5 == 0){ // every 5 frames
        frame = inputFrame.gray();
        compareImage();
    }
    return inputFrame.rgba(); // display frame
```

The things is my frames are bad so the recognition works but not as i want.

For the recognition is use ORB method comparing 2 `Mat` Objects but i don't think my issue is here.

Can someone tell me how to improve my frames ?